# Azure devops pipeline -Downloading artifacts failed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i am building an azure pipeline, i was building my solution successfully but then i started seeing a issue with not being able to download content with the error of "Downloading artifacts failed: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.ArtifactDownloadException: Unexpected error occurred while downloading artifacts ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Git-lfs installation failed with exit code: 1"
I can see in the log it started with git saying "git: 'lfs' is not a git command."

If i sign into the privately hosted build agent i can run "git lfs version" the command successfully runs.

If i switch of LFS all my powershell scripts fail with the error cannot 
"##[error]The term 'powershell.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

I have tried switching over to the azure powershell which loops on the script twice which isn't good for business.

I have tried both Microsoft public and my private build server with the same result "git: 'lfs' is not a git command.".

I have rebuild the first tasks with the same result with error  on a new pipeline.

Any ideas or logs i can inspect?

Answer (score 0):

Add the path to Git-LFS to your `PATH` environment variable, and restart your private build agent.